# How to Renew Expired Metadata for SSO/SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, metadata, saml-2.0

I am trying to host a metadata file and act as an IdP.

To generate the metadata I used the following online tool https://www.samltool.com/idp_metadata.php

After filling out the form and building it, the `validUntil` attribute is set to be the current timestamp.

When trying to test this metadata with https://samltest.id/upload.php it says expired.

When I increment the year and try again the metadata date doesn't seem to change.

How can create an IdP metadata file that is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually change the `validUntil` value according with your requirement. There won't be any issue during validation on the aforementioned site.

To verify, I just quickly ran through changing the field value and my input meta-data passed the validation.

[original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P11kgFNQXCMgll3aHctwCORPZJpNh9b-/view?usp=sharing)
and [updated](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WsgQrf5srZLdzTRSb68Mu89IV7COF-YA/view?usp=sharing)
results.